# Flask Sqlalchemy data order is changing after any commit

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using PostgreSQL with sqlalchemy. I have a model like this

```
class User(UserMixin, ResourceMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    active = db.Column('is_active', db.Boolean(), nullable=False,
                   server_default='1')
    score_by_admin = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=True, default=0)
    submitted_date = db.Column(db.DateTime(),  default=datetime.datetime.now, index=True)
```

User data is showing in a html table order by submitted_date. I am changing data with model method like this:

```
    def active_user(self):
        self.active = True
        db.session.commit()
```

The problem is, If I change any value of User table, Data order also changing. So Html table data order is changing after any data update. Data order is important for my case.

Comment: What do you mean by "data order changing"? What exactly is changing?

Comment: Html table row order

Answer (score 0):

this problem because you define the submitted_date with default=datetime.datetime.now, everytime you update the data, submitted_date will be change to new date

Comment: no, I am not updating submitted_date. datetime.datetime.now() only set datetime first time it is created.